# In what condition db's b-tree index can become unbalanced?

Tags: indexing, database-administration, b-tree

I received an interview question today that surprised me.

> You have MySQl with b-tree indexes, after what operations and in what
> cases b-tree can become unbalanced?

I thought, that it always calculate and balance b-tree index after operations. So, do you have any idea?

Comment: I would reply by asking ‘define unbalanced’, and I am a B-tree author. Stupid interview question.